# I want this video link download able in PHP or html

Tags: php, html, jquery, laravel

How to directly download video form the external link like that
https://rr4---sn-4wg7ln7k.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?expire=1659178416&ei=ULnkYojCCteA2LYP6fy9gAY&ip=18.207.249.128&id=o-AH5lc61_k63NQzB0KfAwR3eKkWwyf6UlhiglXm4yeZ1G&itag=244&aitags=133%2C134%2C135%2C136%2C137%2C160%2C242%2C243%2C244%2C247%2C248%2C278%2C597%2C598&source=youtube&requiressl=yes&spc=lT-KhmC1OQXH6E1Bwoi7FX0xjBgFfGU&vprv=1&mime=video%2Fwebm&ns=VbQMOPVRVjJo8hxCD1PMQ88H&gir=yes&clen=21400428&dur=460.000&lmt=1659122075115614&keepalive=yes&fexp=24001373,24007246&c=MWEB&txp=7319224&n=vuqpLdTQIjRGZJYI&sparams=expire%2Cei%2Cip%2Cid%2Caitags%2Csource%2Crequiressl%2Cspc%2Cvprv%2Cmime%2Cns%2Cgir%2Cclen%2Cdur%2Clmt&sig=AOq0QJ8wRgIhAKjNSNNnW-Zi3_qeXCI3N6Stx9M1BoTKyXMlU5_xlZMHAiEA_tGiCCCcd37kVTJHmE7AxiJHlSw05UJY_MFHBcNEKpE%3D&rm=sn-p5qe7r7e,sn-uxaxovg23-aixe7l&req_id=e29350f8131ca3ee&ipbypass=yes&redirect_counter=2&cms_redirect=yes&cmsv=e&mh=iR&mip=103.7.79.121&mm=29&mn=sn-4wg7ln7k&ms=rdu&mt=1659156550&mv=m&mvi=4&pl=24&lsparams=ipbypass,mh,mip,mm,mn,ms,mv,mvi,pl&lsig=AG3C_xAwRgIhAJWZ4pMz_cCq37cAARiY6120pKwzb2lMPiKEQa4A-lqXAiEAz-wXlSB2hoxwLu-V3nPL69zGhF0cJ9CxDvMLEuUUvrQ%3D***emphasized text***

Answer (score 1):

Just add your link download attribute in html tag:

```
<a href="video.mp4" download>
```